# Problems using string::find_first_not_of and string::find_last_not_of

Tags: c++, string, stl, erase

I know this problem crops up a lot, but I couldn't find a piece of code which worked for me.

I am trying to strip all punctuation off of an incoming string using find_first_not_of and find_last_not_of methods in the string library:

```
//
//strip punctuation characters from string
//
void stripPunctuation(string &temp)
{
    string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    size_t bFound = temp.find_first_not_of(alpha); 
    size_t eFound = temp.find_last_not_of(alpha);

    if(bFound != string::npos)
        temp.erase(temp.begin());
    if(eFound != string::npos)
        temp.erase(temp.end());
}
```

Basically, I want to delete anything at the front of the string that is not alphabetic and anything at the end of the string which is not alphabetic. When this function gets called, it results in a segmentation fault. I am not sure where I should be passing bFound and eFound?

Comment: What is your question? What is your problematic input? Have you noticed that you never pass `bFound` or `eFound` to `.erase`, so your code makes a wild assumption?

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault. Sorry, I somehow left that out. I am not sure where to pass bFound or eFound. I tried passing them to temp.begin() and temp.end(), respectively, but got a compiler error. Should they be the second arguments of .erase?

Comment: @dylan What did the STL documentation for `string` say about `erase`?

Comment: it seems erase() only accepts an iterator, which is what i thought initially. so that is what i passed. I basically cobbled this together from an example I found on cplusplus.com, but obviously it is not correct. Forgive my ignorance and sorry for inconveniencing whomever decided to give me negative feedback, btw.

Comment: cplusplus.com examples are error-ridden. Make a testcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never pass .end(). It points to an invalid iterator, which represents the end.
If you want to delete the last character in a string, use temp.erase(temp.length()-1).
If I understand you correctly.

edit:

> it seems erase() only accepts an iterator, which is what i thought initially.

That is not true:

```
string& erase ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos );
iterator erase ( iterator position );
iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Comment: ok, i altered it per your instruction and it still crashed my program.

Comment: Yes, because you delete 2 times. With this code, if you have a string like: ".abcd." it will work. But, if you have "abcd." only it will crash. You need to distinguish between those cases. My advice: iterate over the whole string with an iterator and push out dots with that method.

Comment: OK. i used the iterative approach you suggested and it seemed to work. thanks.

Comment: `.end()` is _not_ an "invalid iterator", though you cannot dereference it.